# If F.Col is less than x, replace with 'string'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a dataframe at the moment. There are a lot of distinct counts of a row and I am trying to reduce it down by converting some of the less frequent distinct values into something like "Other". Below I will attempt to illustrate my df and desired df.

This is my current DF:

```
ID   Street
1    Kent
2    Kent
3    Kent
4    Grove
5    Apple
```

This is my desired DF:

```
ID   Street
1    Kent
2    Kent
3    Kent
4    Other
5    Other
```

I would like to do this by count, as in my real dataframe I am trying to limit those results less than 3,000 to return as "Other".

Naturally I have tried things like:

```
df = df.withColumn("Street", when(F.col("Street").count() < 3000, "Other").otherwise(F.col("Street")))
```

But I am experiencing no joy.

What would you do in this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the count over each partition of streets using window function, and use that as the condition in `when`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "Street", 
    F.when(
        F.count("*").over(Window.partitionBy('Street')) < 3000, 
        "Other"
    ).otherwise(F.col("Street"))
)
```